# Getting Bad request While using Transaction API [MarkLogic]

Tags: transactions, marklogic, aws-application-load-balancer, marklogic-10

I encountered a "bad request" error while using my C# code and Postman to access the transaction API. Upon investigation, I observed that when accessing the API through the load balancer, an additional ID is appended to the request URI. However, direct server requests function correctly, providing the expected transaction IDs.
When Requested through Domain
[image: Error Response through load balancer]

When Requested through Server Direct
[image: Response from direct connection]

Interestingly, the request succeeds when using the cURL command.

```
curl --anyauth --user user:pass -X POST -d "" -i -H "Content-type: text/plain" http://DNS:8000/v1/transactions
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68350470/14419